# blender 2.9 curve handles not visible until selected

Tags: bezier-curves

In previous versions once you go to curve edit mode you see all curve control points handles. But in 2.9 it's only dots. To see handles you must select control point first [image]
This is not ok if I want to move two side handles of different control points at the same time (for example I want to select and move only top handles of two points on screenshot). Is there a way to get it back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that's what you're looking for (*Viewport Overlays > Curve Edit Mode > Handles > All*):

[image]